# How can i pass a timer object to a function?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a timer on Each Windows form of my project in vb. Net named "timer" and it works property 
I have a successful code of using the timer but i think its better to avoid  All routine and repeated code in the timer event (Tick) of Each form

How can i pass the timer properties to the Function in my  module
Here is My basic code written in my form

```
Private Sub timer1_tick (ByVal Sender As Object , ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static Second As Integer
    Second +=1
    If second >= 4 Then
          Timer1.Stop() 
           Lbl_Save.Visible = False
           Second = 1
    End If
End sub

Private Sub btn_Save_Click(ByVal Sender As Object , ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Save. Click
    Timer1.Interval = 300
    Timer1.Start() 
End Sub
```

============================

The procedures  i wrote  in my (Setting_Module) contiaing error

```
Public Sub Get_Timer(ByRef form_Name As Form) 
   Static Second As Integer
    Second +=1
    If second >= 4 Then
        formName.Controls("Timer1").Stop() Error
        formName.Controls(" Lbl_Save"). Visible = False
        Second = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

The compiler give Me an error As it cant accept the  (property : Stop)

Any one has a better idea i would be grateful very much for him

Comment: Please do not pass timers around like this. It is better to let each form have its own timer so that they can be properly disposed off when each form closes.

Comment: `formName.Controls("Timer1")` returns an object of type `Control`. It does not have a `Stop()` method.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these timers?

Comment: Don't move form code out into a module.  If you want multiple forms to have common functionality then create a base class that inherits `Form`, add the common functionality there, then have all the other forms inherit that.

Comment: `Timers` are not controls so they will not be in a `Controls` collection.  The requirement for being able to be added to a form in the designer is being a component, which a `Timer` is.  A control is a specialised type of component that adds a UI.

Comment: @Enigmativity well. Timer i use it As a tool instead of messagebox appear to the user.. As soon As clicking on the save button. A Label appear for 4 seconds inform user the process succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
Private Sub btn_Save_Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Save.Click

    Lbl_Save.Visible = True

    Observable.
        Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0)). 
        ObserveOn(Me).
        Subscribe(Sub(x) Lbl_Save.Visible = False)
End Sub
```

Then you're not mucking about with timers at all.

Comment: So use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - iam New to this feature.. Should i put the code in the Public declaration..or on class

Comment: I am afraid i would misuse your useful idea.. How can i improve my understanding of your idea

Comment: And for using classes instead of module sounds great too.

Comment: @Mo_ElSoudy - Why classes instead of modules?

Comment: I think classes are more useful to free up space of memory While compiling the program. Besides ena ke the user to set up As many dll files As he wants.

Comment: I think classes are more useful to free up space of memory While compiling the program. Besides ena ke the user to set up As many dll files As he wants.

Comment: @Mo_ElSoudy - Classes have nothing to do with freeing memory when compiling. Where did you get that idea? Can you show me a reference?